# When I load logo in toolbar title and subtitle do not show

Tags: java, android

When I load image from firebase, and load it in toolbar logo, title and subtitle disappear and logo is moved on center. Here is my code:

```
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions = requestOptions.transform(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(20));


        Glide.with(GroupChatActivity.this).asDrawable().load(uri).apply(requestOptions).into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setLogo(resource);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

            }
        });
    });
```

and activity look like this:

[image]

When I use getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.image); it works fine, Title and subtitle are shown...

Comment: When I use getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.image); it works fine...?? So what is question?

Comment: Where is title and subtitle?

Answer (score 1):

Inside toolbar you can set your own view also. Try to include your toolbar layout view like this way.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

So in that way you define whatever you want. And also control is with you.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I am trying to avoid that solution